# Read analog envelope by 8051

Tags: sensor, analog, c, 8051

I am having a serious issue here. I've bought a Maxbotix XL ultrasonic sensor but I didn't know that it is the AE version, that does not come with pulse width, it comes with Analog Envelope. I have a 8051 board and I need to read these Analog envelope data and measure the distance. I don't know what analog envelope is, but I also have a common analog output, how can I read this data from 8051?

I am very grateful

Answer (score 5):

You don't mention the specific part number that you have; I looked at the datasheet for the [MB1310](http://www.maxbotix.com/documents/MB1210-MB1310_Datasheet.pdf), which is an AE part in the XL series.  The last page of the datasheet shows sample waveforms for the "Analog Envelope" output - it is essentially the unfiltered output of the range sensor.  This would be useful if you want to process multiple return signals, at the expense of extra code complexity.

Here are the datasheet waveforms:

[image: Analog Envelope]

For your application, you may want to use the AN output, which is a voltage output that is ratiometric with distance.  Note that you'll need an extra analog input on your 8051 board to do this.

From the datasheet:

> Pin 3 - (AN) This pin outputs analog voltage with a scaling factor of
>   (Vcc/1024) per cm. A supply of 5V yields ~4.9mV/cm., and 3.3V yields
>   ~3.2mV/cm. Hardware limits the maximum reported range on this output
>   to ~700 cm at 5V and ~600 cm at 3.3V. The output is buffered and
>   corresponds to the most recent range data.

Comment: Your answer turned up first, so instead of adding the same answer I took the liberty of putting the clip (it is for the MB1300 but there is no difference to the function of the pin) I took into your answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Oli, I don't mind at all.  Your answers set a pleasantly high standard, and I could benefit from your "picture worth a thousand words" approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How can I add an extra analog input on my board?

Comment: @ViniciusTavares: What board do you have, exactly?

Comment: I have an AT89S52 microprocessor, the board is a custom one and not developed by me, by the way, I have its electrical scheme: http://i.imm.io/G59P.jpeg

Comment: Pins 1-8 on your 40-pin connector (CNT1/CON40) are tied to the analog input pins on your AT98S52 (pins 39-32 respectively).  Provided that the resolution and accuracy of the on-chip ADC meets your requirements, you can use any open pin in this range.

Comment: Guys, I tried all the weekend to get this AN signal but as I am very new to this, I could not get a successful read. I've already connected my sensor to the P0.1 but I can not find a didactic explanation about how to get the voltage in this pin. Can you guys give me this final help? It will save my year! I am VERY grateful that you guys gave so much attention on my problem!